# How to avoid executing javascript while using Kendo Templates in grids

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-template

I would like my users to enter a kendo template in a UI field for them to customize grid cells. So the user can enter `Hello #= name #` in an input field on the UI, and the grid column will show the result appropriately.

The problem is that the user may enter `# alert('test') #` in the template and the javascript will execute. I'm using ajax in my application and a malicious user may invoke http from the template.

Is it possible to avoid executing javascript in Kendo templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really avoid it, except by sanitizing the input. You could remove round brackets from the templates before applying them so at least there could be no function calls, or remove all `# ... #` from the template with a regex.

Comment: I still need the round brackets as I would like the users to enter conditional styles such as `# if (#= amount # > 1000) style='color:red' #`

Comment: uh..so you want to avoid executing JS while allowing them to execute JS?

Comment: I just want to allow them to define conditional styling. I'm researching other venues, such as LESS

Comment: in a generic way, this is not possible with kendo templates; they are compiled to JS; you could create a DSL that only allows specifying styles for this and then create the template from that (e.g.: input for column name; input for value to compare; input to select >, <, =, input for color(s))